# Has Silver John ever been used in other series?

Tags: character-similarity

I really love Manly Wade Wellman's Silver John stories (and yes, I know he hated that they were called that) and was wondering if he ever appeared (named or unnamed) in other works by Wellman or other creators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_John), there was a movie, *[The Legend of Hillbilly John](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070295/)* and Brian Keene referenced John explicitly in his novel, *[Dark Hollow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Hollow_(novel))*. You can find a list of less explicit depictions in the Wikipedia article.

Not being familiar with the "Silver John" books, I don't know if Hosea Songmaker from Mercedes Lackey's *Spirits White as Lightning* is intended to be a tribute with his silver-stringed banjo, his Ozark ways, and his experience with weird folklore creatures.